# Running sqlite3 with react fails with error

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, node-sqlite3

In my React web app I want to read from local sqlite db file. From what I understand it can be done via sqlite3 service package. After installing `npm install sqlite3` and executing the following code I'm getting an error (Windows machine). Does anyone knows what to do?

```
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose(); 
var db = new  sqlite3.Database(":memory:");
```

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html 1:0
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html>

Comment: did you solve it?